# express - add response header cache-control header not being added

Tags: node.js, angular, express, server-side-rendering

I have an express / node server and i need to add Cache-Control: public to the document request, my code works fine for other headers but whenever trying Cache-Control it doesn't get added and i don't know why.

I tried testing my code to see if it was an issue with actually adding headers but it seems to work for others so i'm doubtful its an issue with my code.

WORKING

```
   server.use((req, res, next) => {
     res.append('Cache-Controllll', 'public');
     next();
   });
```

NOT WORKING

```
    server.use((req, res, next) => {
      res.append('Cache-Control', 'public');
      next();
    });
```

There is no cache-control header added in response headers without any of the above but i do see in request headers Cache-Control: no-cache if that makes a difference.

Comment: try adding `, max-age=<SOMEVALUE>'` as well

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
res.append('Cache-control', 'public, max-age=300')
```